# Update MySQL table with JOIN on the same table?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have a table that stores session hashes which are linked to accounts:

[image: Sessions table]

I would like to update every single entry in the table that belongs to a certain account, but I do not have the `ID` for the account. I have to get it from the same table.

**Currently this is what I do:**

*Note, that the only input for the the whole process is the **Session Hash**, named: `:INPUT_ADMIN_HASH`*

**First I get the adminID:**

```
SELECT admins_adminID FROM `adminSessions` WHERE `adminSessionHash` = :INPUT_ADMIN_HASH;
```

**Then by the obtained adminID I update the same table:**

```
UPDATE `adminSessions` SET `sessionValid` = FALSE WHERE `admins_adminID` = :INPUT_ADMIN_ID
```

**I would like to combine them to a single query:**

```
UPDATE
    `adminSessions` AS a
INNER JOIN
    `adminSessions` AS b ON a.`adminSessionID` = b.`adminSessionID`
SET
    a.`sessionValid` = FALSE
WHERE
    a.`adminSessionHash` = :INPUT_ADMIN_HASH;
```

It does not work: `Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Queries and reconnect.`

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions to disable safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't disable `safe mode` you could try

```
UPDATE adminSessions 
   SET sessionValid = FALSE
 WHERE adminSessionHash = :INPUT_ADMIN_HASH
   AND adminSessionID IS NOT NULL;
```

I don't know if this is enough to convince `MySQL` that you have used a `KEY` column.

P.S. Your `JOIN` is doing absolutely nothing to help by the way.